# Autolayouts: how to center a group with two/one intrinsic elements?

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, interface-builder, constraints

The issue might be not quite unique, but still couldn't find a solution.
The layout is presented on the picture:

[image]

So, I have two elements with different widths, one of which (or both) have it dynamic (the value of the labels can change). So, what I need is to center that, let's call it "group". The labels must be different elements, as I can apply different font sizes and faces. And if that would be a text editor, it would just be one line with different markups. But don't know how to achieve that with Autolayout. Any advice?

**Please** don't advice to put the labels inside of the container and center that container (unless if there is a way to set that container's width (dynamic as well) properly), as **the labels widths are dynamic**, so the question of centering those elements inside of the container is still open.

UPD: Image attached improved.

Comment: What you could do is put both of the labels within a UIView. Then, you can center the view and not have to worry about centering both of them.

Comment: Ok. What is the way to center them inside of the container as well? As I mentioned, the width of the elements is dynamic.

Comment: Well, you could add a constraint that would set the width of the view to automatic. So the views width would simply adapt to the width of the labels. And then from there you'd add another constraint centering the view.

Comment: What does that mean "to add a constraint that would set the width of the view to automatic"? Could you make it the question answer if you sure that would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap them in a view and give that view center of screen.

[image]

*In detail:*

Grap an empty view and drag it to interface builder give it to, centerX and any height constraints, then add 2 labels to it, hook 1st label's leading to that view's leading and give it CenterY constraint, make 2nd label leading equal to trailing of 1st label and hook it's trailing to the view's trailing and give it also centerY constraint that way you have a dynamic view width depending upon it's subviews but this works only with sub-items that have a predefined width or intrinsic content size like labels and buttons.

*In action:*

[image]

Here is a gif on how to create it with constraints

[group intrinsic gif](http://recordit.co/TSmMTvs1sG)

Comment: Please pay attention to the fact, that the labels width is dynamic, so I still need to center them inside of the container in come way, so this is not solving the issue at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "make EqualWidths"? The labels widths must be different.

Comment: Could you draw such layout and attach the image?

Comment: auto layout will detect the bigger and make them equal

Comment: The labels widths must not be equal. This is the core of the question. The centering must be not symmetric for both labels.

Comment: By the group common width size. Same way as you would be editing that in text editor. Updated the image attached.

Comment: Have you tried my solution it will accomplish what you just edit

Comment: Hm... I tried wrapping them into UIView even before posting the question. But what is the way to set that container view its dynamic width to fit the labels widths?

Comment: it's width depends on sub-elements widths just hook the leading of left item to container's leading and hook middle elemnts properly until hooking right most element to the container's trailing

Comment: I don't understand which way I define the container's width dependent on sub-elements widths. Could you clarify on this thing? With Autolayouts usually child elements accommodate parent's width, not vise versa.

Comment: That's sad that you haven't provided actually the constraints visual representation on the animated images, as they are the key of achieving the goal. But yes, I tried that and it works. Thanks!